# Is type 2 superconductivity just type 1 with phonons made from molecular groups rather than atoms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, superconductivity

In type 1 superconductors  atoms lower the energy of cooper pairs Could larger molecular structures be doing this in type 2 superconductors to lower the cooper pair energy? I ask this because in some type 2 superconductors heavy atoms increase the transition temperature and molecules can be far heavier than atoms